# Prove that ${{n+m-1}\choose{m}}$ is the number of ways to select m items from a set of n items with repetitions allowed.

Tags: combinatorics

How do I prove this statement?

As per my understanding, the number of ways to select $m$ items from a set of $n$ items, with repetition, is simply $n^m$, as each round of selection still deals with $n$ items.

Comment: You get $n^m$ if you are choosing a sequence, whereas you get $\binom{n+m-1}{m}$ if you are choosing a multiset. For example, in what you are trying to prove, drawing 3, then 1, then 1, then 2, is equivalent to drawing 1, then 2, then 1, then 3.

Comment: You may find this article helpful:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)